# Remote stream multiple files in SOLR

Tags: streaming, solr

I want to use SOLR's remote-streaming facility to extract and index the content of files.

This works fine if I pass stream.file=xxx as a parameter to the http GET method.

However, I have a lot of these, and want to batch them up (i.e. not have to have a GET per file).

Is there a way I can do this in SOLR?

e.g. I'd like to be able to POST some xml like this:

```
<add>
  <doc stream_file="filename">
    <field name="id">123</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This has been recently asked](http://n3.nabble.com/multiple-binary-documents-into-a-single-solr-document-Vignette-OpenText-integration-td472172.html) (and answered) in the solr-user mailing list.

Comment: This link appears to be dead now. Found two relevant links: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Extracting-and-indexing-content-from-multiple-binary-files-into-a-single-Solr-document-td1916693.html and http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201003.mbox/%3C665c35491003240758l574d38a9t3f6e1f8f132af301@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

I find that multiple ADDs are fast, so long as you only COMMIT the batch and don't try to COMMIT after every ADD.  I would guess that the performance penalty is not worth writing your own RequestHandler.